# Java8 - Count after filter on stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I hope this question was not asked before.
In java 8, I have an array of String `myArray` in input and an integer `maxLength`.
I want to count the number of string in my array smaller than maxLength. I WANT to use stream to resolve this issue.

For that I thought to do this :

```
int solution = Arrays.stream(myArray).filter(s -> s.length() <= maxLength).count();
```

However I'm not sure if it is the right way to do this. It will need to go through first array once and then go through the filtered array to count.

But if I don't use a stream, I could easely make an algorithm where I loop once over myArray.

My questions are very easy: Is there a way to resolve this issue with the same time performance than with a loop ? Is it always a "good" solution to use stream ?

Comment: Also, if you want _smaller than_ then it should be `s.length() < maxLength` and not `s.length() <= maxLength`

Comment: @Aominè does `.parallel()` will help ?

Comment: Did you try it?  Does it work?  If so, this might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.  If it doesn't work, then tell us what error or unexpected behaviour you get.

Comment: @azro running this in parallel might make it worse, as there are a lot of things to consider before even thinking about going parallel.

Comment: And no, it's not always a good solution to use stream, if you care about performance.  There's an overhead in creating a stream.  If your array is quite small, you'd be better off just to use a loop.  If you're dealing with a very large array, you should probably experiment with both solutions, to see which performs better.

Comment: @azro watch out using parallel streams, because they are running by default on the default fork-join theadpool. Only use them if you really need them and you know what you are doing!

Comment: Maybe also a good advice is when you are using streams with filtering is to use custom predefined predicates (named predicates). That will improve the readability of the stream.

Answer (score 6):

> However I'm not sure if it is the right way to do this. It will need
>   to go through first array once and then go through the filtered array
>   to count.

Your assumption that it will perform multiple passes is wrong. There is something calling *operation fusion* i.e. multiple operations can be executed in a single pass on the data;

In this case `Arrays.stream(myArray)` will create a stream object (cheap operation and lightweight object) , `filter(s -> s.length() <= maxLength).count();` will be combined into a single pass on the data because there is no stateful operation in the pipeline as opposed to filtering all the elements of the stream and then counting all the elements which pass the predicate.

A quote from Brian Goetz [post here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-1-brian-goetz/index.html#listing1) states:

> Stream pipelines, in contrast, fuse their operations into as few
>   passes on the data as possible, often a single pass. (Stateful
>   intermediate operations, such as sorting, can introduce barrier points
>   that necessitate multipass execution.)

As for:

> My questions are very easy: Is there a way to resolve this issue with
>   the same time performance than with a loop ?

depends on the amount of data and cost per element. Anyhow, for a small number of elements the imperative for loops will almost always win if not always.

> Is it always a "good" solution to use stream ?

No, if you really care about performance then *measure*, *measure* and *measure*.

Use streams for it being declarative, for its abstraction, composition and the possibility of benefitting from parallelism *when you know you will benefit from it that is*.

Comment: Come on, voters, I can't be the _only_ person who thinks this is a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` instead of `stream` and filter the output.

```
int solution = IntStream.range(0, myArray.length)
                .filter(index -> myArray[index].length() <= maxLength)
                .count();
```